# How to disable a RangeSlider asp.net MVC razor c#?

Tags: rangeslider

Is there any built in property? I tried with different attributes like `@readonly = "readonly"` , `@class = "disabledClass"` and `disabled="disabled"`, but I don't understand why it is not working.

Here is a piece of my code in razor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.olddata "RangeSlider", new { 
       id = "olddata", 
       minValue = 1, 
       maxValue = 10, 
       defaultValue = 6,
       stepValue = 1
})
```